# Android ConstraintLayout layout views on top of each other plus extra height

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In my layout file I have a `ConstraintLayout` as the parent and 2 child views.

1. Player View (displayed with ratio of 16:9)
2. Controls View

I need to layout the player controls on top of the player view (cover it) and add `10dp` of height so it goes even a little higher than the player view.

Is there a way to achieve this with `ConstraintLayout` without adding more `ViewGroups` to the picture?

Comment: use frame layout

Comment: I need `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` from `ConstraintLayout ` to set the ratio of my player view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Place a `Space` view on top of the player. Make the height of the `Space` view `10dp`.
2. Constrain the control's top to the top of the `Space` view and its bottom to the bottom of the player.

The `Space` view will not show but will help to provide the positioning you want.